# How to send email with DKIM to BCC using Chilkat using C# .Net

Tags: dkim, chilkat, bcc

My question is about sending bcc with dkim using chilkat.
I have suceesfully sending emails for past several years using Chilkat. I came across a new requirement where i need to BCC sent emails. Previously, I was using
I am adding bcc like

```
email.AddBcc("name","bcctest@bcc.com");

Chilkat.Dkim dkim = new Chilkat.Dkim();
Chilkat.MailMan mailman = new Chilkat.MailMan();
Chilkat.Email email = new Chilkat.Email();
mailman.SendMimeBytes(email.BounceAddress, email.GetToAddr(0), dkimSignedMime);
```

I am using SendMimeBytes to send emails.
dkimSignedMime contains the cert info and email object mime. Using this same method I am unable to send BCC.
I tried

```
mailman.SendEmail(email);
```

It sends out email but it goes to Junk.

I assign BCC property of email to the relevant email address before converting to mime. But this does not work as expected as BCC info is removed from mime. Is there a way i can achieve this functionality keeping the integrity intact?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that shows how to send DKIM signed email, and also explains how to add BCC email addresses.

https://www.example-code.com/csharp/dkim_send_email.asp